# PyCharm IntelliSense is not working with streamz lib

Tags: python, pycharm, intellisense, jetbrains-ide

I have the following problem. PyCharm does not offer auto-completion for the **streamz** lib.

[image: PyCharm code completion]

In Jupyter notebook I get the desired function displayed:

[image: Jupyter code completion]

I have tested it in PyCharm and IntelliJ, both code completion does not work correctly. The project interpreter in PyCharm is correctly selected `venv\Scripts\python.exe`, the package is also shown to me.

Does anyone know any advice?

Comment: Does project interperter show `streamz` in installed packages under project interperter settings?

Comment: Yes its shown to me under the project interpreter.

Comment: does pycharm autocompletes other packages?

Comment: So far, I haven't had any problems with that. If it is not so, then I did not notice it.
I have the same problem with IntelliJ and the package.
I already uninstalled and reinstalled Pycharm.
I also started several projects (Anaconda, Python 3.x, Python 2.x) same problem.

Comment: Did you try to drop cache? or delete `.idea` + `.iml`?

Comment: I did. Uninstalled Pycharm and then deleted the program directory. I also started a completely new project and tried it again. No change.

Comment: No more reproducible with streamz=0.6.2